# PHP add to session with button

Tags: php, session, button, session-variables, shopping-cart

I'm creating a basic shopping cart script , located at php/cart.php, with a GET for "action" and a switch for it that either adds or removes a variable from the $_SESSION, or unsets it altogether. What's the easiest way to create a button that, when clicked, uses this script to manage the session items?

Also would it be better to try and refresh the div containing info from the session, or just refresh the whole page?

Comment: try using ajax to dynamically update php

Comment: Your question is very localized.  Are you asking whether or not to do a full page refresh by making the button submit to a script or whether you should use ajax?  Functionally the two are essentially the same and the differences would be largely aesthetic or reliant upon your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this answer might not be appropriate, as you did not list ajax or jQuery in your question, but I would do it in the following way:

First I would make a button with a call to a function:

```
<button onClick="add_to_session('a_value')">Name</button>
```

Then in the javascript, aided by jQuery:

```
function add_to_session(val){
    $.post("phpPage.php",{
        passedValue:val
    },function(ret){
        // maybe do something here...
    });
}
```

Then on the php page I would just:

```
$_SESSION['new_val'] = $_POST['passedVal'];
```

This is a very simple example.  It is just to illustrate the basics of a simple technique.  Hope it helps.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks